# Find Shapes in a Pdf using Spire.Pdf

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, pdf-extraction

We have some code to redact certain phrases in a Pdf document that is working fine. This is some important code to us, so I'm trying to write some tests around this to make sure that when asked to redact a phrase it does, it's in the right place, colour, opacity, etc. I cannot find how to do this in code.

Here's how we are adding the redaction boxes

```
private static void HideText(PdfPageBase page, string text, TextFindParameter searchFindParameter)
{
    var textFindCollection = page.FindText(text, searchFindParameter);
    
    if (textFindCollection is null)
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (var textFind in textFindCollection.Finds)
    {
        page.Canvas.DrawRectangle(PdfBrushes.Black, textFind.Bounds);
    }
}
```

The only populated collection in `page` after this `PageLayers`, but I've not found anything of use in there. `ExtractImages` returns nothing, which is not surprising as these are Shapes.

I imagine I need to cast something as something else to be able to get to the Shapes, but I cannot find out what. I found an example that went through `Section` `Tables`, but I cannot find a `Tables` collection anywhere.

Comment: This is just one step in the protection of a document, like middleware. Other steps deal with metadata, images, removing text from the document, etc. I want to test this step is working as it should

Comment: Yes, a later step may be to take the document and save it as an image to further remove data. This is not addressing my question of how to find the redactions to ensure they are present and correct though

Comment: For future readers I want to stress that, as @KJ mentioned, your above code does not redact anything. For testing purposes you have to "tag" somehow your black box so that you find your shape and not a similar one when you extract the shapes (not sure if SpirePDF supports shape extraction, better check with their support)

Comment: The fact that I'm using it for redaction is not relevant to the issue. I am adding shapes to a document and I want to unit test that process, so I need to identify if they are there and correct. Is there a way to get shapes in a document in Spire?